# How do I correctly configure path alias with Jest in Next.js app?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs

I'm working on a Next.js project (JS, no TS) and I configured an absolute path alias for imports (`"@*": ["src/*"]`). I just installed Jest, tried writing a test but getting the following error:

```
Configuration error:

Could not locate module @jest/expect mapped as:
/Users/tomchestnut/dev/nhl-dashboard/src/$1.

Please check your configuration for these entries:
{
  "moduleNameMapper": {
    "/^@(.*)$/": "/Users/tomchestnut/dev/nhl-dashboard/src/$1"
  },
  "resolver": undefined
}
```

I added the jest.config.js file according to the Next.js [docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/testing#jest-and-react-testing-library) and added the moduleNameMapper object to try and match the path alias, but I can't seem to get this working correctly.

Any help with how to correctly configure this is appreciated!

My config files are below.

jsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@*": ["src/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

jest.config.js:

```
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({
  dir: './',
});

/** @type {import('jest').Config} */
const customJestConfig = {
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', '<rootDir>/'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
  },
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

Comment: The issue is that you're mapping all `@*` imports to the `/src` folder, but `@jest/expect` is a `node_modules` dependency (not a local import). Usually, it's good practice to avoid using `@` for absolute imports within your project as that will conflict with any published packages that starts with `@`. Try using something like `@/*` instead for absolute local imports (or any other variant as long as it's not just `@`).

Comment: Thanks! Changing my import alias to `@/*` in jsconfig and updating moduleNameMapper to `'^@/(.*)$'` in jest.config fixed my issue.